# Use component A's return value in Component B

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component.

```
//Component A

import * as React from "react";

interface IProps {
  length: number;
  width: number;
}

export default function Test(props: IProps) {
  const { length, width } = props;
  const someNumber = 12;
  let returnNum: number = 0;
  returnNum = (length * width );

  return <> { returnNum } </>; 
}
```

I want to return the `returnNum` to the following component

```
// Component B

import * as React from "react";

interface IProps {
    returnNum: number;
}

export default function GetValueToThisFunction(props: IProps) {
    const { returnNum } = props;
    let valueRet = 0;
    if (returnNum < 1) {
        valueRet = 400;
    } else if (returnNum >= 1 && returnNum < 2) {
        valueRet = 300;
    }
}
```

I am using my component the following way

```
<Test length={18} width={3}/>
<GetValueToThisFunction returnNum={} />;
```

I basically want to pass `Test` component return value (returnNum) and use that for `GetValueForThisFunction`

Comment: You're having a hard time because React isn't meant to be used this way. It renders things to the DOM. Can you just use a function `computeArea` to get the computed value?

Comment: @bflemi3, my actual code is not as simple, I am making reusable components so had to write a short smaller example that can be posted here and I can understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: Understood @Maddy. Please see my answer using higher order components.

Comment: If you want to have a "common source of truth" for a variety of components consider using a store like e.g. redux.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [higher order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) to render your component.

```
const withArea = Component => ({ length, width }) => (
    <Fragment>
        {/* render whatever you want here */}
        <Component area={length * width} />
    </Fragment>
);

const ComponentWithArea = withArea(MyComponent);

const App = () => (
    <ComponentWithArea length={5} width={10} />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I understand that `<Test>` and `<GetValueToThisFunction>` are siblings. I would change `<Test>` component adding a new callback prop:

```
//Component A

import * as React from "react";

interface IProps {
  length: number;
  width: number;
  updateNum: (num: number) => void; // 1. Add new callback props
}

export default function Test(props: IProps) {
  const { length, width, updateNum } = props;
  const someNumber = 12;
  let returnNum: number = 0;
  returnNum = (length * width );

  updateNum(returnNum); // 2. Call the new callback, passing in input the returnNum

  return <> { returnNum } </>; 
}
```

Now you can save the `returnNum` returned from `<Test>` using the callback, save it into the state and then pass it to `<GetValueToThisFunction>` using the state:

```
<Test length={18} width={3} updateNum={(newNum) => this.setState({newNum})}/> 
<GetValueToThisFunction returnNum={this.state.newNum} />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import * as React from "react";
import B from "path/to/B";

interface IProps {
  length: number;
  width: number;
}

export default function Test(props: IProps) {
  const { length, width } = props;
  const someNumber = 12;
  let returnNum: number = 0;
  returnNum = (length * width );

  return <B returnNum={returnNum}/>; 
}
```

Comment: Will this still return me `returnNum` for component A?

Comment: Do you mean that if the returnNum would change Component B would refresh with the new value?

Comment: I want to return value from component A as well as component B not just component B.